# Background iPhone app for Jailbroken phones

Tags: iphone, background, jailbreak

I develop apps for jailbroken phones, and I need my app to be backgrounded and to be able to keep running as usual when backgrounded.
 On iOS3.0, I would just block the thread at applicationWillTerminate, and that'd be it. But it seems that the fast app switching method in 4.0 is disabling applicationWillTerminate, so I can't use that anymore.
I've tried overriding applicationSuspend by calling it, but that doesn't appear to work either.
Do you guys have any idea how to do this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to intercept the new methods triggering the quasi-backgrounding process set by Apple.

-(void)applicationWillResignActive

-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground

-(void)applicatonWillEnterForeground

-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive